# Выбор максимума из одного поля и значения другого поля по максимуму третьего поля

Tags: sql, postgresql

Коллеги, прошу совета. Есть таблица, например, `table`, с тремя полями, например `field1, field2, field3`. Надо получить в одном запросе два значения:

1. Максимум поля `field1`
2. Значение поля `field2` в записи, где поле `field3` максимально.

Значения поля `field3` уникальны, так что оба ответа однозначны.

Решить эти две задачи двумя запросами не проблема.

1:

```
SELECT MAX(field1) FROM table;
```

2:

```
SELECT field2 FROM table 
ORDER BY field3 DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

или для второй задачи вариант с `WHERE`:

```
SELECT field2 FROM table 
WHERE field3 = (SELECT MAX(field3) FROM table);
```

Но получить оба в одном запросе - не получается. Пишу что-то такое:

```
WITH max_field3 AS (
SELECT field3 FROM table WHERE field3 = (SELECT MAX(field3) FROM table))
SELECT MAX(field1),  max_field3.field3 FROM table;
```

Пишет missing FROM-clause...

Если пишу так:

```
WITH max_field3 AS (
SELECT field3 FROM table WHERE field3 = (SELECT MAX(field3) FROM table))
SELECT MAX(field1),  max_field3.field3 FROM table, max_field3;
```

Пишет - нужен GROUP BY

В общем, что-то я не понимаю, прошу совета.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два хорошо оптимизированных запроса (надеюсь, соответствующие индексы в наличии). У которых между собой ничего общего, кроме таблицы-источника, нет. Причём каждый запрос возвращает строго одну запись. В таких условиях решение по объединению очевидно. CROSS JOIN.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT MAX(field1) field1 
    FROM table 
    ) t1
CROSS JOIN ( 
    SELECT field2 
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY field3 DESC LIMIT 1
    ) t2
;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Причем "спасибо" не только за это конкретное решение, но и за мое знакомство с `CROSS JOIN'. Я не знал об этом. Решение рабочее и быстрое в выполнении.

Comment: Ого, не ожидал, что cross join хорошо оптимизирован.

Answer (score 3):

Костыль:

```
select
  max(a) as a,
  max(c * 10000 + b) - max(c) * 10000 as b,
  max(c) as cd
from tbl
```

Нормально:

```
select
  (select max(a) from tbl) as a,
  b,
  c
from tbl
order by c desc
limit 1
```

---

Проверял на

```
create table tbl (a integer, b integer, c integer);
insert into tbl (a, b, c) values (1, 7, 1);
insert into tbl (a, b, c) values (2, 3, 2);
insert into tbl (a, b, c) values (3, 2, 7);
insert into tbl (a, b, c) values (4, 1, 6);
insert into tbl (a, b, c) values (5, 4, 3);
insert into tbl (a, b, c) values (6, 5, 4);
insert into tbl (a, b, c) values (7, 6, 5);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Очень лаконично и, казалось бы, очевидно, но я упустил. Рядом коллега @Akina предложил решение с CROSS JOIN - оба решения рабочие, я провел замеры, решение с CROSS JOIN работает на 10% быстрее. Теперь сижу размышляю за счет чего, так как на вид они делают одно и тоже.